# Connection timed out using dbcp 2

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, struts

I am using struts 1.2, hibernate 3, spring 2 and tomcat as the server in my project. I have implemented connection pooling using dbcp 2 (jdk version 1.7.0_03). I am using MySql as a database. In spite of implementing dbcp2 the connection times out every day. I am getting the following exception.

```
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - ERROR - JDBC begin failed
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection.close() has already been called. Invalid operation in this state.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMutex(ConnectionImpl.java:3015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4789)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:496)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:322)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:615)
    at com.tcg.service.user.UserService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dc6eec0f.getUserDetails(<generated>)
    at com.tcg.delegate.user.UserDelegate.getUserDetails(UserDelegate.java:127)
    at com.tcg.common.CommonUtil.InactiveUser(CommonUtil.java:209)
    at com.tcg.util.AutomatedProcess.run(AutomatedProcess.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have googled for solutions but the suggested solutions could not solve my problem.

Here is my hibernate config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory name="hibernate.session-factory.SRS">
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">ITSDEV</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my application context file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <!-- My SQL database Connection -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://172.20.25.185:3306/itsdev"/> 
      <property name="username" value="itsdev"/>
      <property name="password" value="itsdev"/>      
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Here is a Sample DAO class I am using in my application :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import com.tcg.common.CommonUtil;
import com.tcg.dto.ItsUserMaster;

public class CopyOfLoginCheckDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport{
   @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    public boolean CheckCredentials(String loginId, String password, Map map)  {
        boolean retVal = false;
        List<ItsUserMaster> userData = new ArrayList<ItsUserMaster>();
        try{

        HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate(); 
        userData=template.find("from ItsUserMaster itsUserMaster where itsUserMaster.loginId='"+loginId+"' and itsUserMaster.loginCred='Y' and itsUserMaster.deleteFlag!='Y' and itsUserMaster.active!='I' and itsUserMaster.itsCorporateMaster.active!='I' and itsUserMaster.itsCorporateMaster.deleteFlag!='Y' and itsUserMaster.itsUserTypeMaster.deleteFlag!='Y' and itsUserMaster.itsUserTypeMaster.active!='I' and itsUserMaster.itsDepartmentMaster.active!='I' and itsUserMaster.itsDepartmentMaster.deleteFlag!='Y'");

        if(userData.size()>0){

            ItsUserMaster itsUserMaster = (ItsUserMaster)userData.get(0);
            String pwd = CommonUtil.decode(itsUserMaster.getPassword().toString());
            String loginCred=itsUserMaster.getLoginCred().toString();
            if(loginCred.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                retVal = true;
            }

        }
        } catch (Exception sqlexcep) {          
            sqlexcep.printStackTrace();
            retVal = false;
            System.out.println("Exception occured while getting Connection to the database");
        } 
        return retVal;
    }

}
```

If you need further information please let me know. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your DAO class also in which you are facing this exception ? Also, are you getting the issue in all of the DAO methods or any specific methods ?

Comment: I am facing the issue in all the DAO classes , for example, I cannot even login to my application.  I have added the DAO class in the question.

Comment: Your hibernate and spring is too old relatively to the jdbc driver. Revert back to jdbc 3, or just remove hibernate and spring from your app and use native jdbc 4.